# PHP Select MYSQL select id from Array

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have this array:

```
    $_SESSION['id'] = array();
```

I would like to select all array ID'S and then select them from the database.
How to do it? I have no idea..

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you need exactly. This is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql='select name from table where id in ('.implode(",",$_SESSION['id']).')';
```